# If Jacobi iterations converges to $Ax=b$ then $A$ is invertible.

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

> Prove or Disprove:
> If Jacobi iterations converges to $Ax=b$ then $A$ is invertible.

I think this is true but not sure how to connect between $A$ and $B_J$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $B_J:=I-D^{-1}A$, assume there is an $x\neq 0$ such that $Ax=0$. It means that $B_Jx=x$. Hence $\rho(B_J)\geq 1$ and the Jacobi method is not convergent.